# Angular: Identification of Model Annotation are not identified by Angular Code

Tags: angular, typescript, annotations

I'm working on an Angular application where I have a Model object with properties of different types. I did an annotation in the model to application know when it's needed another type of Input. Unfortunately, the application does not recognize it:

Here's my code:

app.component.ts:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { Model } from './model/model';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: './app.component.css'
})
export class AppComponent {

  model = new Model();
}
```

app.component.html:

```
<app-register-module [model]="model" ></app-register-module>
```

register-module.component.ts:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-register-module',
  templateUrl: './register-module.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./register-module.component.css']
})
export class RegisterModule
{

@Input() model!: { [key: string]: any };

getModelProperties(): Array<keyof Persistable> {
  if (this.model) {
    const propertyNames = Object.keys(this.model) as Array<keyof Persistable>;    
      
    return propertyNames;
  } else {
    return [];
  }
}

capitalizeFirstLetter(str: string): string {
  return str.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + str.slice(1);
}

isIdProperty(property: string): boolean {
  return property.toLowerCase() === 'id';
}

onSubmit() {
  if (this.model) {
    for (const property of Object.keys(this.model)) {
      console.log(property + ':', this.model[property]);
    }
  } else {
    console.log('Model is null or undefined.');
  }
}    

isPriceProperty(model: any, property: string): boolean {      
  const category= Reflect.getMetadata('category', model, property);
  console.log('category: ' + category);
  if(category=== 'price'){
    console.log(property + " is price");
  }
  else{
    console.log(property + " is not price");
  }
  return category=== 'price';
}
}
```

register-module.component.html:

```
<form (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
    <div *ngFor="let property of getModelProperties()" class="mb-3">
    <ng-container *ngIf="isPriceProperty(model, property)">
        <mat-slider
          [min]="0"
          [max]="100"
          [step]="0.01"
          [(ngModel)]="model[property]">
        </mat-slider>
        <span>{{ model[property] | number: '1.2-2' }}</span>
      </ng-container>
      <ng-container *ngIf="!isPriceProperty(model, property)">
        <input
          type="text"
          class="form-control"
          [id]="property"
          [name]="property"
          [placeholder]="'Insert' + capitalizeFirstLetter(property) + ':'"
          [(ngModel)]="model[property]">
      </ng-container>
</div>
<div class="row">
        <button type="submit">Record Data</button>     
</div>
</form>
```

model.ts:

```
export class Model 
{
   text!: string;
   @Category('price')
   number!: number;
}
```

annotations.ts:

```
export function Category(category: string) {
    return (target: any, propertyKey: string) => {
        Reflect.defineMetadata('category', category, target, propertyKey);
    };
 }
```

It's printing:

```
register-module.component.ts:45 category: undefined
register-module.component.ts:50 id is not price
register-module.component.ts:45 category: undefined
register-module.component.component.ts:50 number is not price
```

Obviously, the number does not appear as a scrollable-floating input of two decimal places in HTML cause Angular is not identify number
as a price.

Answer (score -1):

It looks like you have an error in your tag in the `app.component.html` file. You are opening the `<app-register-module>` tag but you are closing it with `</app-principal>`. The opening and closing tags must match. Fix this to:

```html
<app-register-module [model]="model"></app-register-module>
```

Also, based on your problem description, I recommend checking a few things:
The problem described is related to the non-identification of the annotation (or decorator) `@Category('price')` in the model. Here are some steps to troubleshoot and fix the issue:

1. **Dependencies**:

   - Make sure you have the `reflect-metadata` library installed in your project. If not, install it using npm or yarn:

     ```
     npm install reflect-metadata
     ```
   - In your project's main file (usually `main.ts` or `polyfills.ts`), add the following line at the top:

     ```js
     import 'reflect-metadata';
     ```
2. **Check Decorator**:

   - Make sure the `@Category` decorator is being applied correctly. The code looks correct, but it's always good to review.
3. **Access to Metadata**:

   - When trying to access metadata, make sure you are doing it correctly. In your code, you are using `Reflect.getMetadata(...)`. This seems correct, but make sure you are passing the correct arguments.
4. **Compilation**:

   - TypeScript needs to be configured to output design information to reflection. In your `tsconfig.json`, make sure you have the following options:

     ```json
     {
       "compilerOptions": {
         "experimentalDecorators": true,
         "emitDecoratorMetadata": true
       }
     }
     ```
5. **Runtime Check**:

   - Sometimes the problems may not be in the code, but in the way Angular is running or initializing. Make sure there are no other errors in the console that could be causing this behavior.
6. **Code Revision**:

   - Review the component and template code to ensure there are no typographical or logic errors that could be causing the issue.

If after following these steps the issue persists, it may be helpful to create a minimal reproducible example on a platform like StackBlitz or CodeSandbox. This will allow other developers to help identify and fix the issue more easily.

Hope this helps solve your problem!